# DB - Saving Locations efficiently to enable searching close by

Tags: database, location

Currently designing a DB and backend for a new app, I am looking for a solution to save locations (how they are represented does not really matter, so it would be possible to store them with the complete address, or only the coordinates) and filter through them to display other records to the user that are close to a user-chosen record.

If I have thousands of records in the table, I do want to search for some records that are physically close by (e.g., +/- 0.5 degrees in longitude and latitude) to a single one. Would it be the most efficient to just save the coordinates, then go from the coordinates and use SQL-`FILTER` to search for those that match a specific mathematic formula (like the +/-0.5 degrees), or is there a better DB-type (never worked with Graph-DBs, but that might be something to look into)?